# Import package using user input -- Python v3.6

Tags: python, terminal, console, python-3.6

Uhm, this is my first question that I do in Stack Overflow, so let's just go to the point. :)

I'm creating a program with Python v3.6 and it is a like terminal, my plan is do like the programming languages(C#: "console.write"). The commands will be stored in a folder called "lib" and it will have folders to separate the commands, so the thing will be just like this:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- lib-

  - console-

  - - write.py

  - - see.py

  main.py

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So, as you can see there's the folder "lib", inside it has the folder "console" and inside the folder has 2 files "write.py" and "see.py". My mission is when the terminal starts the user type a command like: "$ console.write Hello World", doing that the program will separate the "console" from "write" creating a list ["console", "write"]. Now the terminal will see if "console" is a folder, if it exists so the terminal will check if "write"+".py" is a file, if so it will import the file and pass the args "Hello World", the basic structure that the command needs is two lines: "class exec:" and "def main(args):":

```
class exec:
    def main(args):
        # The rest of the command here.
        print(args)
```

With everything allright the terminal will import the file and execute the class "exec" and execute the def "main" passing all the arguments to it resulting in:

```
$ console.write Hello World
Hello World
$
```

The same to "see.py":

```
$ console.see /home/user/documents/file.txt
This is a file that contains some text, really interesting.
$
```

Thx if someone help me. ;) Have a good day!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your question comes down to "how do I import a module if I only have a string variable containing its name?" If that is what you want to do, look at the built-in function `__import__()`,

Comment: Yeah, I know the function, but the the script is separated in packages(folders) so I tryied:
`c = input('$ ').split(' ') # User responds with "console.write Hello World" returns ["console.write", "Hello", "World"]` ||| 
`path = c[0].split('.') # Returns ["console", "write"]` ||| 
`args = c[1:] # Returns ["Hello", "World"]` ||| 
`module = '.'.join(path) # Returns "console.write"` ||| 
`module = __import__(module)  # Returns an error message` |||
`module.exec.main(args) # Aren't executed` |||
And an error pop out the console.

Comment: In that case, you were on the right track, but could not make it work. Please put the code that you tried in your question and explain why it doesn't do what you want. (It's difficult to make sense of code in a comment.)

Comment: Sorry, I'll recreate the question